# why this code compiles (url is not a keyword)?

Tags: c#, url, keyword

I have this code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("iexplore");
            http://www.google.com;
            Console.WriteLine("maximize"); 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

It's not clear to me why this code compiles? Because I have an url there and it's not a c# keyword...

Comment: Try adding `goto http;` in the end and you'll understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# doing

```
someText:
```

makes a label for a `goto`, after that the

```
//Some other text
```

is a comment so

```
http://www.google.com;
```

is the label `http:` followed by the comment `//www.google.com;`